# Angular $http is sending OPTIONS instead of PUT/POST

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to Update/Insert data in a MySQL database through a PHP backend. I'm building the Front End with AngularJS and using the `$http` service for communicating with the REST API.

My setup looks like this:

**I'm setting the header via the $httpProvider:**

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'};
```

**And the POST-Call looks like this:**

```
   return $http({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: campaign
    });
```

**The Dev Console in Chrome shows me this:**

[image]

When I change from POST to PUT, I'm sending an OPTIONS call instead a PUT. And the content-type switches just to `content-type`.

**My  request payload is send as an object:**

[image]

> How do I set my header properly?

---

**EDIT:**

The PHP backend sets some headers:

```
   $e->getResponse()
              ->getHeaders()
              ->addHeaderLine('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

   $e->getResponse()
              ->getHeaders()
              ->addHeaderLine('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

> Is there something missing?

Comment: application/json is a default content-type set. You need to search in your code if somewhere you are setting it to text/plain

Comment: @Chandermani My code is fairly small. I have one api.js file where I do it, and one .config.js file where I set currently the header manually.

Comment: I agree with the consensus. Your Headers shouldn't be needed. Something very odd is going on. I look through every `http.post` I've written in Angular and they were all simple. The headers were assumed.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it.

**What was the problem?**
The CORS workflow for DELETE, PUT and POST is as follows:

[image]

What it does, is:

1. Checking which request is gonna be made
2. If it's POST, PUT or DELETE
3. It sends first an OPTION request to check if the domain, from which the request is sent, is the same as the one from the server.
4. **If not**, it wants an Access-Header to be allowed to send this request

> Important here: An **OPTIONS request doesn't send credentials**.

So my backend server disallowed the PUT request.

**Solution:**
Putting this inside the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.php [QSA,L]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sub.domain:3000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

After this, **create an empty .php file called blank.php inside the public folder.**

EDIT: As one commenter pointed out, instead of creating an empty PHP file, you can add this rewrite rule to your .htaccess file\;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
```

**To clarify:**

1. I already sent the Access-Control-Header
2. What it solved was the first two lines, and
3. Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the specific subdomain with Port

Best website I could find to [learn more about CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/?redirect_from_locale=de).

Comment: Instead of creating blank.php,  we can use this 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]`

Comment: Thanks @gruberb. Your information helped me to understand why I got OPTION instead POST.

Comment: Congratulations. I have never seen such a complete CORS explanation as this.

Comment: Its in general not only confined to angular

Comment: or you can add header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding");
to your php script - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJAe8cZmMAs

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify your `$http` headers manually, it is all done for you behind the scenes and they are automatically set to `application/json` for `POST` and `PUT` type requests. So all that you should do is

```
$http.post(url, data);
$http.put(url, data);
```

Comment: I removed it, but then I'm sending an OPTIONS call instead a PUT/POST. If I set them, at least I'm sending the right call.

Comment: @gruberb, you should trying to read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The DELETE method has by default content-type: text/plain