# Angularjs preflighted get request

Tags: angularjs

I need to make a get request to this url: 
`http://action.metaffiliation.com/trk.php?mclic=N4CD1F1015&argann=test`

when I do it via curl
`curl 'http://action.metaffiliation.com/trk.php?mclic=N4CD1F1015&argann=test'`
everything works fine, I do get the GIF object I'm expecting.

When I run this get request using `$http.get` using AngularJS, it first runs an OPTIONS request that fails.

I've checked [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and have added what I think are the correct headers to make a simple request:

```
$http.get('http://action.metaffiliation.com/trk.php?mclic=N4CD1F1015&argann=test', {
        headers: {'Accept': 'image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8', 
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
});
```

Still no luck.

any idea ? 
P.S: the url that I'm hitting is supposed to be called in a `img` tag

thanks

Comment: Did you observe, you are missing the 'http' protocol..

Comment: I have but it doesn't change anything. Also what I forgot to mention : I don't have access to the server I'm trying to reach

Comment: It should be `$http.get('http://action.metaffiliation.com/trk.php?mclic=N4CD1F1015&argann=test', ...`

Comment: I know I've tried it too, it doesn't change anything, I'll update my question

Comment: Have a look at my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254277/angular-http-is-sending-options-instead-of-put-post/30328731#30328731

Comment: thanks @gruberb the problem in this case is that A/ it's a GET request, B/ I can't do anything on the server I'm trying to reach

Comment: @MikeW you definetly have to talk to your backend people how the request has to look like to get accepted. If you are using a public API, read the docs.

Comment: @gruberb thanks a lot for your help. I don't think it has to do with the distant server tho, cause I'm pretty sure the options request doesn't even reach the distant server

Answer (score 0):

ARRGHHHH. This was just coming from the fact that I had an ad blocker turned on !
Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks a lot for your help