# Why the rewrite rule does not convert to GET from OPTIONS

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, apache2

In my website has many JS files and I want if a particular JS is loaded in the browser then rewrite will call a servlet in another domain.

For this I have added following lines :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mydomain.com
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/someresource.js
 RewriteRule ^/someresource.js http://anotherdomain.com/bin/test/custom [R=301,L]
 </VirtualHost>
```

When I see the output in the browser console, it says that Http Method OPTIONS was executed instead of GET call. As a result I am not getting the desired output which is supposed to execute in this call http://anotherdomain.com/bin/test/custom

The servlet(/bin/test/custom) has only doGet method.

If I hit this url directly in the browser mydomain.com/someresource.js then redirect works correctly. But it does not work when the browser loads someresource.js

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably an issue with CORS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254277/angular-http-is-sending-options-instead-of-put-post

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a rewrite is what you need here.
If you want to have a redirect, use

```
Redirect 301 /someresource.js http://anotherdomain.com/bin/test/custom
```

If you want to hide the redirect from the user, so you rather use your webserver as a proxy, use mod_proxy:
*https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html*

hth