# GET request is not called after successful OPTIONS call in angular with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement login functionality using angular and spring boot.

Im following spring tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/
But in my case my angular project is hosted on localhost:4200 and spring on localhost:8080

Now im sending a '/user' request to spring server. My angular code look like:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders(credentials ? {
        authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)
    } : {});

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080'+'/user', { headers: headers }).subscribe(response => {
        if (response['name']) {
            this.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            this.authenticated = false;
        }
        return callback && callback();
    });
```

Now because of CORS it sends OPTIONS request which is successful with status 200. 
After this it is not sending actual GET request which should send credentials as [Angular $http is sending OPTIONS instead of PUT/POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254277/angular-http-is-sending-options-instead-of-put-post)

My spring code looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, allowedHeaders={"x-auth-token", "x-requested-with", "x-xsrf-token"})
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

Also i have added Spring Security in pom file.

Can you please help to find out why GET request is not triggered after OPTIONS request.

Comment: Can you check browsers developer tool(network tab)

Comment: My Response Header look like:
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 03 Jun 2018 09:16:14 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`

Comment: Is this your OPTIONS response??

Comment: Yes its my Response Header for OPTIONS request

Comment: Is there any other call happening at browser after the success of OPTIONS??

Comment: Like, the GET call is made by the browser but server not receiving.. we can see that in networks tab. Please check it once more..!!

Comment: No after OPTIONS request is successful there is no request that is being sent

Comment: Alright, that means browser is not making the GET call on behalf of your code. !!

Comment: Lemme understand it once again with response header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root Cause:**
In your spring security, you allowed only three types of request headers, i.e. `allowedHeaders={"x-auth-token", "x-requested-with", "x-xsrf-token"}`

But, in your `http.GET` request you are doing the basic authentication using header name as `authorization` which is rejected by `Spring Security`. So, the spring responses the allowed headers to your browser (i.e. preflight request with OPTIONS method) and your browser sees that.. Ooops.. `authorization` header is not allowed so I can't proceed with original GET call.

**Solution:**
Allow `authorization` header also in your spring security. It should work.!!

Comment: Is there any way like throw exception on console that server has rejected this request?

Comment: Actually, server is not rejecting it, server is telling your browser that I allow only these requests.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar those preflight requests are actually a security check performed by the browser before making calls to cross origin servers. And, in response, they get set of criteria that are allowed by server, based on those criteria browser checks for your request, if it is valid with those so called criteria, then only browser makes the original call. Hope it makes sense..!!